# Allow user to add and resize shapes

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I want to allow a user to add shapes/resize them, with a shape panel like the one on this page:

https://logomakr.com/

I have read into this and the use HTML canvas seems inevitable. My issue is allowing the user to add more than 1 of each shape and allowing the user to resize each shape.

Comment: you need to use `javascript` for achieving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using a JavaScript canvas library, called [**FabricJS**](http://fabricjs.com/).

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

function addRectangle() {
   var rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
      top: 65,
      left: 65,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      fill: '#03A9F4'
   });
   canvas.add(rectangle);
}

function addTriangle() {
   var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
      top: 65,
      left: 65,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      fill: '#4CAF50'
   });
   canvas.add(triangle);
}

function addCircle() {
   var circle = new fabric.Circle({
      top: 65,
      left: 65,
      radius: 25,
      fill: '#f44336'
   });
   canvas.add(circle);
}
```

```css
body { margin: 10px 0 0 0 }
canvas { border: 1px solid #ccc }
button { margin-top: 9px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.14/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
<button onclick="addRectangle()">Add Rectangle</button>
<button onclick="addTriangle()">Add Triangle</button>
<button onclick="addCircle()">Add Circle</button>
```

To learn more about this library, refer to the [official documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/).